mdadm: Restoring RAID 10 on synology nas
I apologize for my English.
Recently, one of my disks in the Synology NAS failed, and I decided to replace all disks with higher-capacity ones. First, I replaced the faulty disk with a larger-capacity disk (Disk 1) following Synology's instructions, and everything went smoothly.
Then, I replaced another functioning disk with a larger-capacity disk (Disk 2). During the RAID recovery (synchronization) process, at around 90%, some error occurred, and I found in the web interface that both of my new disks (Disk 1 and Disk 2) were in critical status. I read online that I could replace the last installed disk and continue with the RAID recovery (synchronization), so I replaced Disk 2 with a new clean disk (Disk 3). This was probably my mistake. The Synology NAS web interface did not offer to recover my storage pool as it did previously. The new disk (Disk 3) just showed up as healthy, and that was it.
After a lot of reading on forums, I decided to use the CLI to attempt RAID recovery, and here is what I have:
Disk 3 - sata4
Disk 1 - sata3
I'm not sure if this is the right way.
Using fdisk, I created partitions on sata4 based on sata3.
With the following commands:
sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sata4p1
sudo mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sata4p2
sudo mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sata4p3

I added the corresponding partitions to raid10.
Currently:
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]
md2 : active raid10 sata4p3[5](S) sata3p3[4](E) sata2p3[3] sata1p3[2]
      7792588416 blocks super 1.2 64K chunks 2 near-copies [4/3] [E_UU]

md3 : active raid1 nvme1n1p1[0] nvme0n1p1[1]
      244193984 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sata4p2[0] sata3p2[1] sata2p2[3] sata1p2[2]
      2097088 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sata4p1[1] sata3p1[0] sata2p1[3] sata1p1[2]
      8388544 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>

$  sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 13 14:54:17 2022
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 8388544 (8.00 GiB 8.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 8388544 (8.00 GiB 8.59 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Jul  6 23:37:15 2024
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 66c55d68:831b4099:05d949f7:b0bbaec7
         Events : 0.58225

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sata3p1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sata4p1
       2       8        1        2      active sync   /dev/sata1p1
       3       8       17        3      active sync   /dev/sata2p1

$  sudo mdadm -D /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 13 14:54:20 2022
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2097088 (2047.94 MiB 2147.42 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 2097088 (2047.94 MiB 2147.42 MB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Jul  6 21:05:57 2024
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : f52a567f:3734ea2b:05d949f7:b0bbaec7
         Events : 0.137

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       50        0      active sync   /dev/sata4p2
       1       8       34        1      active sync   /dev/sata3p2
       2       8        2        2      active sync   /dev/sata1p2
       3       8       18        3      active sync   /dev/sata2p2
$  sudo mdadm -D /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 13 15:16:49 2022
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 7792588416 (7431.59 GiB 7979.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3896294208 (3715.80 GiB 3989.81 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Jul  6 23:26:24 2024
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K

           Name : nas:2  (local to host nas)
           UUID : 2894354f:67be6652:bbba583f:6cbe1629
         Events : 65803

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       35        0      faulty active sync set-A   /dev/sata3p3
       -       0        0        1      removed
       2       8        3        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sata1p3
       3       8       19        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sata2p3

       5       8       51        -      spare   /dev/sata4p3

The partitions on sata4 were added as spares everywhere. md0 and md1 recovered automatically. md2 did not recover automatically, probably because of the faulty state of /dev/sata3p3.
Did I choose the right path?
What are the next steps I should take?

Over time, I noticed that my Synology NAS had independently removed disk 3 from md0 and md1 (sata4p1, sata4p2). After checking the backups, I rebooted the NAS, and disk 1 automatically switched to 'active sync set-A.' The web interface allowed me to perform the recovery, and it was successful.

Eject all your new disks (you might event want to mount them with Linux or whatever and wipe them off), put working original one back and kick rebuild once again. You should be fine!

One of my disks was faulty (power supply errors), and I replaced it with a new higher-capacity disk. I described it above as Disk 1. Currently, Disk 1 is in a faulty state.

Okay; you replaced a working disk (you don't name it, so I'll call it Disk B) with Disk 2 (which was faulty) and Disk 3. What I would have done when Disk 2 went faulty was to put Disk B back in... but at this point, I suspect you may have lost your data. Backups can be your friend.
